# opengl c++: glBlendEquationOES was not declared in this scope error

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I assume I am forgeting to include something, but it is odd because i am using other opengl functions.  How do I find out what I am not including?

Comment: It says no such file or directiory, I have #include <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h> and 
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h> (PS it's for iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like glBlendEquationOES is only an extension for OpenGLES1.1

In version 2.0 it's a core function, just called glBlendEquation.